# Update Table After User Click using button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am doing a basic jQuery ajax call on a PHP file and I can't seem to figure it out, why it isn't working. Any help is appreciated.

jQuery

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#approve').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var email=$("email_address").text();
            changeTable(email);
        });
        return false
    });
    function changeTable(email){
        $.ajax({type:"post",
            url:"DB_Update.php",
            data:{email:email},
            success:function(response){
                alert(response);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

PHP

```
$email=$_POST['email'];

updateTableApproval($email);
public function updateTableApproval($email){
    $query_string="UPDATE users SET approved = b'1' WHERE email='$email'";

    $result=mysqli_query($this->db->connect(),$query_string);

    return $result;
}
```

PHP MAIN

```
echo "<td id='email_address'>".$email."</td>";
echo "<td id='approve'>"."<input type='radio' ".($row['approved']==1?'checked':'unchecked').">"."</td>;";
```

Comment: What part isnt working, do you get any errors or anything ?

Comment: your php function doesn't produce any output ...should always send something back at least for your own validation. Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network for clues. Will see status, data sent/returned, headers etc

Comment: no errors  the code is not responding

Comment: @kaka_2 for you to have "unresponsive code" that means that your code kind of works, but actually produces no output to analyze. Please add some debug (`console.log();` for JS) and let us know

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning data back from php function. Change  one of this.

`updateTableApproval($email);` *to* `echo updateTableApproval($email);`

**OR**

`return $result;` *to* `echo $result;`